# Как привести два метода в разных классах к одному типу?

Tags: c#

У меня есть два класса. PostgreSQL и SQLite.
В первом определен метод `GetGUIDsFromPG()` во втором `GetGUIDsFromSQLite()`. Каждый метод возвращает `List<string>`.

Теперь мне нужно выполнить их пересечение. Пишу:

```
 DataExistInSQLiteButNotInFB = sqllite.GetGUIDsFromSQLite().Intersect(GetGUIDsFromFB());
```

Однако студия ругается, что невозможно привести тип одного к типу другого. Вопрос -- как быть? Как я понимаю тут проблема лишь в том, что у них разные классы.

Определение (каждое в своем классе):

```
public List<string> GetGUIDsFromSQLite()
{

}
```

--

```
 public List<string> GetGUIDsFromFB()
{

}
```

Cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: добавьте в вопрос полное сообщение об ошибке, если обе функции возвращают список строк проблем быть не должно. Скорее всего они возвращают что-то еще, либо идет попытка присвоить переменной с другим типом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`, а присвоить пытаешься переменной с типом `List<T>` получаешь ошибку.

Для решения нужно вызывать [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) у результата

```
DataExistInSQLiteButNotInFB = sqllite.GetGUIDsFromSQLite().Intersect(GetGUIDsFromFB()).ToList();
```

либо изменить тип переменной `DataExistInSQLiteButNotInFB` на `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Спасибо, а у шарпа нет проблем с тем, что переменные в разных классах к пример сравнивать нельзя?

Comment: @Suliman, не понял вопрос. Если к ним есть доступ в данной точке программы - значит можно, если нет - нет

Comment: у меня почему-то
`DataExistInSQLiteButNotInFB = sqllite.GetGUIDsFromSQLite().Intersect(GetGUIDsFromFB()).ToList();`

такое чувство пытается не сами значения а объекты пересечь. Пишет: `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Comment: @Suliman, нужно полное сообщение об ошибке

Comment: Он просто на косноль выводит эту строку. Такое чувство что он пытается сравнить два метода, а не того, что они возвращают.

Comment: @Suliman, без кода позволившего бы воспроизвести ошибку ничего сказать нельзя. Скорее всего тут не ошибка, а просто неверная попытка вывести элементы списка, вместо `Console.WriteLine(list)`, попробуй `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",list))`

Comment: Ну вот что я пытаюсь сделать http://www.everfall.com/paste/id.php?q38e2oghs10e

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39620/discussion-between-grundy-and-suliman).

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - сделайте базовый интерфейс-обертку для ваших классов работы с БД и работайте с объектами типа этого интерфейса.

Например:

```
public interface IDbBase { }

public class PostgreDB : IDbBase { ... }

public class SQLite : IDbBase { ... }
```

после этого создаете объекты ваших классов как

```
IDbBase postgre = new PostgreDB(); 
IDbBase sqlite = new SQLite();
```

и реализуете ваш `Intersect`.